# How to split the fullname column value into 3 columns and remove parenthesis between data using spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split full name into three columns, remove the value in parenthesis and star sign as fullname,First Name and Last Name Using spark SQL. I tried with Regex and split but no avail. Can any one help me with the code snippet.
example:

| Fullname |
| --- |
| Nayaka,Malya (Nayaka) |
| Toyoda,Masayuki *Toyoda * |
| Suzy,Thamas *FUNCTIONAL * |

Expected output:

| Fullname | Firstname | Lastname | Fullname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nayaka,Malya (Nayaka) | Malya | Nayaka | Nayaka.Malya |
| Toyoda,Masayuki *Toyoda * | Masayuki | Toyoda | Toyoda,Masayuki |
| Suzy,Thamas *FUNCTIONAL * | Thamas | Suzy | Suzy,Thamas |

Comment: schema of DF is?

Comment: @thebluephantom : actually my table resides in HBase.

Comment: u may wish to amend the question

Comment: I trying to do some transformations for the fullname coulmn like how I explained in above formate using  spark SQL  and load into HBase.

Comment: spark.sql("select regexp_replace(split(fullname, ',')[1] as FIRSTNAME from employee").show() . I have integrated HBase table to Hive.

Comment: Working or not then? But the initial column is just a string.

Comment: I will look later. It is doable but working now.

Comment: I am able to get firstname, but the same logic is not applying for lastname. iam getting the output like Lastname = Nayaka (Malya)/ Suzy *FUNCTIONAL*. I not able to remove the content in parenthesis and star sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
spark.sql(""" select    split ( ltrim(rtrim(regexp_replace(split(fullname, ',')[1], '[^a-zA-Z ]', ''))), ' ')[0] as FIRSTNAME,
                        ltrim(rtrim(regexp_replace(split(fullname, ',')[0], '[^a-zA-Z ]', ''))) as LASTNAME from employee   """).show(false)
```

Comment: No problem, glad to have been of assistance. A few nice pointers in the question.